# Angular 2 Interface- implementation error

Tags: interface, angular2-template

I am getting the following error trying to implement an interface.

```
Build:Type '{ code: string; name: string; gender: string; annualSalary: number; dateOfBirth: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'IEmployee[]'.
```

Here is the interface

```
//file employee.ts
export interface IEmployee {
    code: string;
    name: string;
    gender: string;
    annualSalary: number;
    dateOfBirth: string;
//method
    computeMonthlySalary(annualSalary: number): number;
}
export class Employee implements IEmployee {
    constructor(public code: string, public name: string, public gender: string,
        public annualSalary: number, public dateOfBirth: string) {
    }
    computeMonthlySalary(annualSalary: number): number {
        return annualSalary / 12;
    }
}
```

I am trying to implement it in employeelist.component.ts

```
//file employeelist.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IEmployee } from './employee';

@Component({
    selector: 'list-employee',
    templateUrl: 'app/employee/employeelist.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/employee/employeelist.component.css']
})

export class EmployeeListComponent {
    employees: IEmployee[];
  // employees: any[]; //this works fine
    selectedEmployeeCountRadioButton: string = 'All';
//getting error on  this.employees 
    constructor() {
   this.employees ={code:'emp101',name:'Tom',gender:'Male',annualSalary:95500,dateOfBirth:'12/6/1981'}];
    }
}
```

Please guide!

Answer (score 0):

The object you declared does not have the computeMonthlySalary method

try this

```
import { IEmployee, Employee } from './employee';
//...
this.employees =[new Employee('emp101','Tom','Male',95500,'12/6/1981')];
```

Comment: Because you need to import the Employee class. I edited the answer